# How to login to ASP.NET Core MVC application from Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular 5 application which uses a REST API for its back-end process. And other is pure ASP.NET Core MVC application.

Both have their own `AccountController`. I have to make an integration in a way that the Angular application has to call the ASP.NET MVC application. When it calls the ASP.NET MVC application, it has to login to that application and returns the Razor page. From this point, user will access the ASP.NET MVC application.

Both the applications have their own databases. But the user details will be stored in both applications.

My question is, how to achieve this?

If any article or documentation is available, it would be helpful if you share it.

Comment: Token oriented authentication seems like a way to go e.g jwt

Comment: use JWT Authentication http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api